# Creating a Chat With Server Socket Channel

Tags: sockets

I'm creating a chat with ServerSocketChannel and maintain communication between Clients - Server.
The server receives a message from the client and broadcasts to every client.
I tried to send a message to the server and everything was fine, but when I try to send a message to the client from the server the message doesn't get there. It only delivers when I close the socket. (It's like it was buffered)

Here's my code for the server:

```
static public void main( String args[] ) throws Exception {
// Parse port from command line
int port = Integer.parseInt( args[0] );

try {
  // Instead of creating a ServerSocket, create a ServerSocketChannel
  ServerSocketChannel ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();

  // Set it to non-blocking, so we can use select
  ssc.configureBlocking( false );

  // Get the Socket connected to this channel, and bind it to the
  // listening port
  ServerSocket ss = ssc.socket();
  InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress( port );
  ss.bind( isa );

  // Create a new Selector for selecting
  Selector selector = Selector.open();

  // Register the ServerSocketChannel, so we can listen for incoming
  // connections
  ssc.register( selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT );
  System.out.println( "Listening on port "+port );

  while (true) {
    // See if we've had any activity -- either an incoming connection,
    // or incoming data on an existing connection
    int num = selector.select();

    // If we don't have any activity, loop around and wait again
    if (num == 0) {
      continue;
    }

    // Get the keys corresponding to the activity that has been
    // detected, and process them one by one
    Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
    Iterator<SelectionKey> it = keys.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      // Get a key representing one of bits of I/O activity
      SelectionKey key = it.next();

      // What kind of activity is it?
      if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) ==
        SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) {

        // It's an incoming connection.  Register this socket with
        // the Selector so we can listen for input on it
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        clientList.add(new Client(s));
        System.out.println( "Got connection from "+s );

        // Make sure to make it non-blocking, so we can use a selector
        // on it.
        SocketChannel sc = s.getChannel();
        sc.configureBlocking( false );

        // Register it with the selector, for reading
        sc.register( selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ );

      } else if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_READ) ==
        SelectionKey.OP_READ) {

        SocketChannel sc = null;

        try {

          // It's incoming data on a connection -- process it
          sc = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
          boolean ok = processInput( sc );

          /* HERE, TRYING TO SEND A TEST MESSAGE BACK */
          ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);
          bf.clear();
          bf.put("testmessage".getBytes());
          sc.write(bf);

          // If the connection is dead, remove it from the selector
          // and close it
          if (!ok) {
            key.cancel();

            Socket s = null;
            try {
              s = sc.socket();
              System.out.println( "Closing connection to "+s );
              s.close();
            } catch( IOException ie ) {
              System.err.println( "Error closing socket "+s+": "+ie );
            }
          }

        } catch( IOException ie ) {

          // On exception, remove this channel from the selector
          key.cancel();

          try {
            sc.close();
          } catch( IOException ie2 ) { System.out.println( ie2 ); }

          System.out.println( "Closed "+sc );
          ie.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }

    // We remove the selected keys, because we've dealt with them.
    keys.clear();
  }
} catch( IOException ie ) {
  System.err.println( ie );
}
 }
```

On the server, please note the lines:

```
ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);
bf.clear();
bf.put("testmessage".getBytes());
sc.write(bf);
```

This is where I try to answer back.

Client receives the messages in a method:

```
// Main method for incoming
public void run() throws IOException {
    while(true) {
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String answer = br.readLine();
        printMessage(answer);
    }
}
```

Regards,
Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems here.

- You're reading lines but you're not writing lines. Add a line terminator when sending.
- You need to close the channel immediately you get -1 from `read()`. You almost certainly can't send on it after that.
- You don't need to cancel the key or close the socket of the channel. Closing the channel does all that.
- Your client read loop needs to break when you get null from `readLine()`.

Comment: That was actually the problem. I didn't even noticed the readLine, because I'm used to use it for everything...

Thanks, sometimes we need to explain the code to someone until we really notice what we though could never be...